# LeetCode 399 Evaluate Division using Scala

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, scala, immutability

In order to gain familiarity with Scala I am trying to solve the following problem

https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-division/description/

> You are given an array of variable pairs equations and an array of real numbers values, where equations[i] = [Ai, Bi] and values[i] represent the equation Ai / Bi = values[i]. Each Ai or Bi is a string that represents a single variable.
>
> You are also given some queries, where queries[j] = [Cj, Dj] represents the jth query where you must find the answer for Cj / Dj = ?.
>
> Return the answers to all queries. If a single answer cannot be determined, return -1.0.
>
> Note: The input is always valid. You may assume that evaluating the queries will not result in division by zero and that there is no contradiction.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> **Input:** equations = [["a","b"],["b","c"]], values = [2.0,3.0], queries = [["a","c"],["b","a"],["a","e"],["a","a"],["x","x"]]
> **Output:** [6.00000,0.50000,-1.00000,1.00000,-1.00000]
> **Explanation:**
> Given: a / b = 2.0, b / c = 3.0
> queries are: a / c = ?, b / a = ?, a / e = ?, a / a = ?, x / x = ?
> return: [6.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0 ]
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> **Input:** equations = [["a","b"],["b","c"],["bc","cd"]], values = [1.5,2.5,5.0], queries = [["a","c"],["c","b"],["bc","cd"],> ["cd","bc"]]
> **Output:** [3.75000,0.40000,5.00000,0.20000]
>
> **Example** 3:
>
> **Input:** equations = [["a","b"]], values = [0.5], queries = [["a","b"],["b","a"],["a","c"],["x","y"]]
> **Output:** [0.50000,2.00000,-1.00000,-1.00000]
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - 1 <= equations.length <= 20
> - equations[i].length == 2
> - 1 <= Ai.length, Bi.length <= 5
> - values.length == equations.length
> - 0.0 < values[i] <= 20.0
> - 1 <= queries.length <= 20
> - queries[i].length == 2
> - 1 <= Cj.length, Dj.length <= 5
> - Ai, Bi, Cj, Dj consist of lower case English letters and digits.

I wanted to use Scala and as much Functional Programming as possible, but I used mutable maps. I know it's not a huge sin, but I suspect I am missing something substantial and I'm not getting the benefits of functional programming. Here is my code, every piece of advice is more than welcome, but my focus is on avoiding mutable maps.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

object Solution {
    def calcEquation(equations: List[List[String]], values: Array[Double], queries: List[List[String]]): Array[Double] = {

        val resultMap: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String, Double]] = mutable.Map.empty
        for (i <- equations.indices) {
            val from = equations(i)(0)
            val to = equations(i)(1)
            val v = values(i)
            if (!resultMap.contains(from)){
                resultMap(from) = mutable.Map.empty
            }
            if (!resultMap.contains(to)){
                resultMap(to) = mutable.Map.empty
            }
            if(!resultMap(from).contains(to)) {
                resultMap(from)(to) = 1/v
                resultMap(to)(from) = v
            }
        }
        val valToInd: Map[String, Int] = resultMap.keys.zipWithIndex.toMap
        val m = valToInd.size

        def solve(myList: List[String]): Double = {
            if (myList.length >= 2 && (valToInd.contains(myList(0)) )  &&(valToInd.contains(myList(1))) ) {
                val unseen = Array.fill[Boolean](m)(true)
                def solveRec(from: String, to: String, curVal: Double): Double = {
                    if(from==to){
                        curVal
                    }else if (unseen(valToInd(from))) {
                        unseen(valToInd(from)) = false
                        val resultList = resultMap.get(from).toList.flatten.map { case (key, mVal) =>
                            solveRec(key, to, mVal * curVal)
                        }
                        resultList.maxOption.getOrElse(-1)
                    } else {
                        -1
                    }
                }
                solveRec(myList(1), myList(0), 1)
            } else {
                -1
            }
        }
        
        queries.map(solve).toArray
    }
}
```